# Which API route design conforms to best practices?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

While designing URI's that are RESTFul, for an ASP.Net Web API App, written in C#, I am finding myself stuck in a quandary, on what is best-practice.

Take the following pseudo-code.

```
public class File{
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;
}

public class X {
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public List<File> Files {get;set;}
}

public class Y  {
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public List<File> Files {get;set;}
}

public class Z  {
 public int ID {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public List<File> Files {get;set;}
}
```

Now, If i want a specific file I would call something like:

```
/api/Files/{ID}
```

Now, If i want the files related to another resource, do I create routes:

```
/api/X/{xID}/Files
/api/Y/{yID}/Files
/api/Z/{zID}/Files
```

Or do I do something like:

```
/api/Files/X/{xID}
/api/Files/Y/{yID}
/api/Files/Z/{zID}
```

In terms of maintenance, the latter option seems more appropriate; anything to do with files is contained in the same controller.

Though the former option seems more explicit to me, somehow, though means spreading similar calls throughout controllers

Or, is there a different way it should be tackled?

Comment: Since the classes aren't encapsulating any different kinds of data, is there a reason you wouldn't or couldn't use a single overarching information class with an additional property that can flag whether it is X, Y, or Z?

Comment: Perhaps, though this is a very general example of the main question - so what happens when a new class `W` comes in and has a list of `P` and each of those P are files - if you see what i mean. Guess i am after what would be best practice. I want the file, but have an X id - which way do i go...

Comment: HOW is this Opinion based?? and the downvote? There are best practices in place and i am not sure what they are...

Comment: @Darren, it's not really opinion based but there has been a segment of the community that thinks stackoverflow isn't a question and answer site.  I'll try to provide my answer in a follow up comment since I can't provide an "Answer"

Comment: @Darren As a rule of thumb, your resource interface should not necessarily match the implementation details beneath it.  The non-answer to your question is that it really depends on what kind of interaction model you are trying to expose at your service wall.  

Is this area of your domain more file oriented or is more "X, Y, and Z" oriented? An answer to this will answer your major question as to whether "Files" goes beneath your "X,Y,Z" or if your "X,Y,Z" go beneath your "Files." If you are designing this from the inside-out rather than "down to the service" and "up to the service"...

Comment: @Darren ...you can set yourself up for some nasty gotchas that don't really manifest themselves until it is far too late.  Think of how you want clients to interact with your system. That is your answer on "what" your service layer should expose.  What happens behind are purely the implementation details of "how" to provide to that service. My advice is to not treat your web api as wrapping a transport mechanism over your application's internals. Treat your web api as *the wall* between your calling clients and your system.

Comment: @K.AlanBates - thanks for the info. That segment of the community need a slap :) - We are the ones consuming our own API; though you just never know when parts may become public, which is what spurred me to ask the Q. I have been tending to lean towards my first idea as files are typically an entity that belong to something else; there just happen to be lots of things that can have files.

Comment: @Darren `re:...just never know` ...that's really where experience just has to kick in to know how flexible is flexible enough, how likely you are to actually take something public, and how much work you are juggling between "going one step further just in case", "damn this will be hard to change if we don't make it just a bit more robust" and "we ain't gonna need it." There really isn't a good, prescriptive answer for managing that.

Comment: @Darren I can say that what has always served me well at balancing these is to keep your service hosts small and focused on simple things and let clients integrate with the services that they require. Segmenting the domain between multiple service hosts tends to create some friction with people whose sensibilities are RPCish and lend themselves more towards designing a monolithic "can be only one!" service api. But, more often than not, keeping them as small as possible pays off for me in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome feedback @K.AlanBates. Plenty of great suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case for using json references

http://json-spec.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html

Im not sure the example is particularly clear, but essentialy you provide the /Files/fileId interface and then in your X/Y/Z objects instead of including the file you reference it

```
{
    "Files" : [{"$ref" : "/file/myFileId"}]
}
```

If you want to provide an interface which returns multiple ungrouped resources, congratulations you have hit a limitation of REST, use POST

---- re comments :

To elaborate on 'use POST'

The RESTful approach would be to use GET for 'getting' resources, however, when you have to pass multiple ids ie GET Files?id=1&id=2&id=3..... you run into the length restriction on urls. This forces you to use POST Files BODY id=1&id=2&id=3..... (or more likely some json request structure) There are several similar questions on this topic on stack overflow with various approaches

Comment: Couple of things. "Use POST" over "REST"? REST is an architectural style, where as POST is one of the HTTP verbs. You would use a POST request in a RESTful system. Not sure I agree with the JSON References either, as JSON is just a way to represent an object, vs actually accessing the resource. Thank you for your answer though :)

Comment: I guess thie thing that stands out from your question is why GET X/{id} dosent return you all the child files of X as part of the json serialized object? My assumption what that they would make it too big, or you might already have them from a Y/{id} request. hence the ref recomendation

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of guidelines out there which explain some best practices for how to design an API.  Ultimately, it is up to the designer to give an API which works well for developers.

In this case, you are talking about two different endpoints: (1) the `Files` endpoint, and (2) some other resource (let's call it `Folders`) which contains files.

Generally speaking, your URL should contain the version of the API (e.g. "v1") and the resource endpoint (e.g. "files").  Thus, your URL will be formed like:

```
1. /api/v1/files
2. /api/v1/folders
```

For querying, you would want to make sure you stick to some standard query string parameters (e.g. `/api/v1/files?id=blah`) as opposed to separating query parameters with a slash mark or other character.

For the other endpoint (`folders`), it may make sense to include the files (or at least the identifiers) in the initial `get`, or it may make sense to require the caller to ask for a specific `folder` out of the set before giving this information.

It is not appropriate to split the object apart by requiring the developer to figure out a complicated URL when they want to get `files` in a `folder`.  If it is not desirable to include the `files` when querying for a `folder`, then it would be better to leave the relation off and allow the client to query for the `files` within a given `folder` by using the query string syntax on the `files` endpoint.

Some helpful links:

- [18F API Standards](https://github.com/18F/api-standards)
- [White House API Standards](https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards)
- [This article](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)

Comment: So, Why would you use `id=`.. vs `/{id}` ? pretty much every resource I have read refers to the latter - when dealing with a primary key (id), unless you're searching something specific from the norm, a name for example vs an ID. Ref the version; yes, i use that - i wrote pseudo code :)

Comment: You could, as long as that is the only unique identifier.  I find the query parameter way to be more clear, but the latter is common enough.

Comment: More often that not, it is - in most systems I've worked with too

Comment: @Darren as a matter of style, I prefer to support both `/{id}` and `?id={id}` the path mechanism is for specifying that the "id" is an intermediate identifier for the thing you're really looking for in some hierarchical data and `?id={id}` is for specifying that "this is the thing I want." The query segment is for identifying resources at the context denoted by the path.  The path segment is for identifying resources within a hierarchy.